# Bootstrap popover hiding if not clicked above it

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is the code I'm working with

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <title>Place Bid</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="popover.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <button class ="bidpopover"><a data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-title="Place Bid" data-container="body" type="button" data-html="true" href="#" id="bid">Place Bid</a></button>
    <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
      <form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group" type ="wage">
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
          <br><br>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>    
          <button type="cancel" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>                               
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Popover UI functionalities-->
    <script src="popover.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.grey-box     /* background of popover box*/
    {
        background-color: gray;
        height: 200px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 2em;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 80px;
    }
  .form-control { /* popover text field*/
    width:120px;
  }
  .popover { /* popover responsiveness*/
    max-width:300px;
  }
  button[type="submit"]{ /* Submit button */
    border: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #45AD00;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 30px;
  }
  button[type="cancel"]{ /* Cancel button */
    border: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #FC3838;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .bidpopover{ /* Place Bid button*/
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 6px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
    border-radius: 5px;

  }
   .bidpopover:hover { /* hovering over "Place Bid" button */
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
  }
```

**ANGULAR.JS***

```
    $( function() /* popover action */
    {
        $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
      html: true, 
      content: function() {
          return $('#popover-content').html();
        }
      });
    } );

    $('body').on('click', function (e) { /* closes popover when clicked outside of it */
    //only buttons
    if ($(e.target).data('toggle') !== 'popover'
        && $(e.target).parents('.popover.in').length === 0) { 
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
    }
});
```

I ran it through the browser and the popover would only function if the mouse click was done above the popover box. Also on a side note, are HTML buttons capable of functioning if clicked anywhere on the button rather than just the button label? My "Place Bid" button would only open the popover if the mouse click happens specifically in the middle area where the button label is.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your code. Edit your question using the snippet tool (`<>` symbol), linking the required resources so we can experience the issue here. Alternatively, you can use jsFiddle or codepen or other online snippet tools. Also, I see you are claiming the script you added, which is clearly `jQuery` is `AngularJS`. You're not including, nor using `AngularJS` in your project. `AngularJS` is not another name for `JavaScript`. It's a distinct library with distinct syntax and distinct methods, which you are not using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's not recommended to place `<a>` tags inside `<button>`s.
I transferred the `popover` functionality to the `<button>`. There were quite a few other minor issues, some related to `HTML` markup, some to `CSS`, which I cleaned and prefixed.

I also fixed a logic error in your `jQuery` code, which was preventing the popover from opening on first click after it had been closed with a click outside the `popover`.

And I colored the popover arrow same as the background color of the popover header (I never understood why it's not default, since the popover opening on bottom will always have the arrow adjacent to its header.)

<kbd>[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/yy62z06d/)</kbd>

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. You fixed the issue, but you made so many changes that I can't learn the mistakes I've made that well because everything in my code was modified.

Comment: At least now you have my version and yours. If you have the time, play in between and see what each mod does. It would have taken me a lot more to comment on each change than just do it. I tried to bring it to a decent "production" level, from my point of view. Let's just say front-end devs are not payed for nothing. :)

Comment: Can you explain the root cause of the button being clickable only on the text? What is the simplest fix to this? I appreciate the time you took to show me your version. I just would prefer simple fixes in my existing code over complete overhauls so that I can apply that practice in the future. Thanks.

Comment: The popover was opening only when you clicked the `<a>` tag, which was confined by the `padding` of the `<button>`. You need to put the padding on the anchor, not on the container, if you want all the container to act as a link.

Comment: Ahh. Gotcha. I just removed the `<a>` tag and put all the properties under the starting button tag which fixed the issue. I don't need this button to act as a hyperlink to another html page, so I just removed the anchor altogether.

Comment: For the popover not closing, is that an issue caused by the HTML code or CSS code? I copy pasted your js code and it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: If it's not working it's because your example is not complete. As you can see, it works in the fiddle.